# How to convert the following text into a proper string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, decode

How to convert the following text into a proper string in C#?

```
&lt;IconStyle xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"&gt;&lt;color&gt;FFFFFFFF&lt;/color&gt;&lt;scale&gt;1.0&lt;/scale&gt;&lt;Icon&gt;&lt;href&gt;root://icons/palette-5.png&lt;/href&gt;&lt;x&gt;192&lt;/x&gt;&lt;y&gt;192&lt;/y&gt;&lt;w&gt;32&lt;/w&gt;&lt;h&gt;32&lt;/h&gt;&lt;/Icon&gt;&lt;/IconStyle&gt;&lt;LabelStyle xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"&gt;&lt;scale&gt;0&lt;/scale&gt;&lt;/LabelStyle&gt;&lt;BalloonStyle xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"&gt;&lt;text&gt;$[description]&lt;/text&gt;&lt;color&gt;FFFFFFFF&lt;/color&gt;&lt;/BalloonStyle&gt;
```

> Forgot to mention the important catch:how to convert the string in a console application in c#?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is HTML encoded, so:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myHtmlEncodedString);
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)
```